# When talking about English 文型, how to say "a sentence"? 文章?

Tags: word-choice, english-to-japanese

I want to talk about English grammar in technical terms. Example, I might want to discuss 文型:

> Every English sentence must have a main verb.

I would say:

> 英文{えいぶん}では、文章{ぶんしょう}にいつも本動詞{ほんどうし}がついている。

To me, saying 文章 in that context sounds good, but the meaning is a little weird. I think of 文章 as really meaning "document(s)".

How should one say "a sentence" in the context of a technical discussion about English sentence structures.

**Note**.  My dictionary defines 一文 as "a sentence", yet I've never heard a native say いちぶん. Though, my listening skills are not the best...

Comment: In case you're interested... _sentence_ [en] = _phrase_ [fr] = _oración_ [es] = 文 [ja] = 句(子) [zh] = 문장(文章) [ko]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you have correctly guessed, 文章 refers to a group of sentences/paragraphs.

To refer to a single sentence, simply use [文](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%96%87), which is perfectly fine as a technical term, too.

一文 means "one sentence". It's used when one needs to emphasize "one".

Answer (score 0):

In such cases, *katakana* センテンス is better, like 「英語のセンテンスには必ず本動詞がある。」, because 文 is ambiguous and can mean "a sentence" or "writings（文章）".  Any good Japanese dictionary must have センテンス as an entry.